# How do I modify the X-Forwarded-For header in Java?

Tags: java

I'm using `URLConnection` to connect to a site. I used `System.getProperties()` to set the `proxyHost` and `proxyPort`, and `connection.setRequestProperty` to change the user-agent.   I haven't seen a way to change the X-Forwarded-For.

Can someone enlighten me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try the below:

```
 connection.addRequestProperty("X-Forwarded-For",VALUE-IP);
```

Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#addRequestProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)